# Concatenate all columns and dump as json in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below:

| id | product_id | agent | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-13 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2021-09-13 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2021-09-13 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-13 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-09-13 |

How can I add a new column with all columns concatenated in json with custom keys like below, the key mappings in json are:

- id -> internal_id
- product_id -> item_id
- agent -> associate_id
- order_date -> transaction_date

| id | product_id | agent | order_date | wanted_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-13 | {**internal_id**: 1, **item_id**: 1, **associate_id**: 1, **transaction_date**: 2021-09-13} |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2021-09-13 | {internal_id: 1, item_id: 2, associate_id: 1, transaction_date: 2021-09-13} |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2021-09-13 | {internal_id: 1, item_id: 3, associate_id: 1, transaction_date: 2021-09-13} |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-13 | {internal_id: 2, item_id: 1, associate_id: 1, transaction_date: 2021-09-13} |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-09-13 | {internal_id: 2, item_id: 2, associate_id: 1, transaction_date: 2021-09-13} |

Eventually the new column will be selected and dumped as json for further. I've been stuck with this for a while. Tried concat and map_from_entries but none of them worked.

I'm using pyspark api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below way, the important functions to be used are the `to_json` and `alias'. I have written it in scala, I am sure can be converted it to python.

```
import spark.implicits._

//just to create the dataset for the example you have given
val data = Seq(
  ("1", "1", "1", "2021-09-13"),
  ("1", "2", "1", "2021-09-13"),
  ("1", "3", "1", "2021-09-13"),
  ("2", "1", "1", "2021-09-13"),
  ("2", "2", "1", "2021-09-13"))
  
val dataset = data.toDF("id", "product_id", "agent", "order_date")

//create the key Mapping programatically by looping if its not static
val keyMapping:Map[String,String] = Map("id" -> "internal_id","product_id" -> "item_id","agent" -> "associate_id","order_date" -> "transaction_date")
val columns = keyMapping.map(f => {
          new Column(f._1).alias(f._2)
        }).toSeq

dataset.withColumn("wanted_column", to_json(struct(columns:_*))).show(false)

//output 
+---+----------+-----+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |product_id|agent|order_date|json_data                                                                           |
+---+----------+-----+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |1         |1    |2021-09-13|{"internal_id":"1","item_id":"1","associate_id":"1","transaction_date":"2021-09-13"}|
|1  |2         |1    |2021-09-13|{"internal_id":"1","item_id":"2","associate_id":"1","transaction_date":"2021-09-13"}|
|1  |3         |1    |2021-09-13|{"internal_id":"1","item_id":"3","associate_id":"1","transaction_date":"2021-09-13"}|
|2  |1         |1    |2021-09-13|{"internal_id":"2","item_id":"1","associate_id":"1","transaction_date":"2021-09-13"}|
|2  |2         |1    |2021-09-13|{"internal_id":"2","item_id":"2","associate_id":"1","transaction_date":"2021-09-13"}|
+---+----------+-----+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly this question is answered here
[How to save a dataframe into a json file with multiline option in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200078/how-to-save-a-dataframe-into-a-json-file-with-multiline-option-in-pyspark)

I use scala so here is what i would do

```
// mock up data, you dont need this if you already have a dataframe ready
val data = Seq(
("1", "1", "1", "2021-09-13"),
("1", "2", "1", "2021-09-13"),
("1", "3", "1", "2021-09-13"),
("2", "1", "1", "2021-09-13"),
("2", "2", "1", "2021-09-13")
)

import spark.implicits._
val df = data.toDF("id", "product_id", "agent", "order_date")

// mocking data is finished here, you now have a dataframe ready to work with

// changing column names to desired names
val new_df = df
.withColumnRenamed("id", "internal_id")
.withColumnRenamed("product_id", "item_id")
.withColumnRenamed("agent", "associate_id")
.withColumnRenamed("order_date", "transaction_date")

// writing json
new_df.write.json("vikas.json")
```

Comment: How can I concatenate the four columns into a single one? As I need to do a groupby later by let's say associate_id. If they are concatenated in a single column, I can use array_agg to merge all columns into one. Otherwise with split json column, it can't be done

Comment: the write to json will create a json record and when you read the data back, it will be one single column with the whole record as a json string. then you can use ```get_json_object``` function to manually extract each field  as an additional column  to the new dataframe where you can do you analysis using aggregations or other functions