# How to write multiline json using pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

We are easy read multiline json using below command

```
df =spark.read.option("multiline","True").json("any multiline.json")
```

but not able to write easily any multiline json using write command

Example of multiline json

```
 [{
  "RecordNumber": 2,
  "Zipcode": 704,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR",
  "State": "PR"
},
{
  "RecordNumber": 10,
  "Zipcode": 709,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
}]
```

I tried using below solution but here aggregating all value and save in text format
[How to save a dataframe into a json file with multiline option in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200078/how-to-save-a-dataframe-into-a-json-file-with-multiline-option-in-pyspark)

could you please suggest any other solution without aggregation and save directly in. json extension

Comment: Could you explain what is your question exactly ?

Comment: How to create multiline json from spark dataframe

Comment: And save in .json extension

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark does not have options to prettify an output JSON, you could convert the result to string JSON using `toJSON` and then use the python json library to save a properly indented json file.

For example :

```py
jsonResults = resultDF.toJSON().collect()
jsonResultList = [json.loads(x) for x in jsonResults]

with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(jsonResultList, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```